# In the Lync LcsCdr database I am getting funky user names

Tags: database, uri, lync

We do custom reporting from the Lync LcsCrd database and on a recent report of people who attended a conference, the userUri for a few select entries are a guid@ourdomain.com

```
1d7e6d4f-9a72-4aaa-b2ea-9761184882fc@ourdomain.com
```

I have tried figuring out where these are coming from, but to no avail. Does anyone know what these are?

Here is an example query that shows these Uris on our database.

```
SELECT distinct u.UserUri
FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[ConferenceSessionDetails] as csd
join McuJoinsAndLeaves as mcu on mcu.SessionIdTime = csd.SessionIdTime and mcu.SessionIdSeq = csd.SessionIdSeq
join Users as u on u.UserId = mcu.UserId

where ConferenceUriId = 1527
```

replace the ConferenceUriId with a valid conference id of your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably this entry is from a dial-in conferencing session. In such sessions, apart from ordinary Lync-enabled corporate users, the following entities are also visible:

- the conferencing attendant and conferencing announcement service users (they both have persistent SIP accounts, however at first sight they look like some garbage similar to your example, but if you watch closely, you will see the "RTC" string in their SIP address)
- anonymous users (via their mobile phone, or

I think your example is about an anonymous dialin conferencing party

Comment: Since it is most likely an unregistered call-in, is there a way to find the phone number they called in with?